# Find a independent variable value from the numerical solutions of a system of differential equations

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I have calculated the solutions for the following system of differential equations using NDSolve

`{x''[t] == 
  Sqrt[(1 - 2 /x[t] + x'[t]^2) (1 + x'[t]^2)]/x[t] - (
   2/x[t]^2 Sqrt[(1 + x'[t]^2)])/(
   Sqrt[1 + x'[t]^2] - Sqrt[1 - 2/x[t] + x'[t]^2]), 
 y'[t] == x[t]/(x[t] - 2) Sqrt[1 - 2/x[t] + x'[t]^2]}`

I would now like to find the value of t for which x(t)==2. I have tried with Solve in this way: `Solve[x[t] /. sysSol == 2, t]`, but it does not work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: In addition to root-finding, one can do this dierectly in `NDSolve` with the `WhenEvent` mechanism.

Comment: How would you do that Daniel? I am thinking of making it print the value of t like `WhenEvent[y[t] == 2, t]`, but I am definitely doing something wrong

Comment: There is an example in `NDSolve` documentation. I suspect what you tried is close. Maybe use `x` instead of `y`? Or use `Sow[t]` as the event (don't forget to `Reap` it around the `NDSolve`)?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given any idea what your initial conditions are so I made some up and solved for a value that was in the range of the solution.

```
sols = NDSolve[{x''[t] == Sqrt[(1-2/x[t]+x'[t]^2) (1+x'[t]^2)]/x[t] -
  (2/x[t]^2 Sqrt[(1+x'[t]^2)])/(Sqrt[1+x'[t]^2]-Sqrt[1-2/x[t]+x'[t]^2]), 
  y'[t] == x[t]/(x[t] - 2) Sqrt[1 - 2/x[t] + x'[t]^2],
  x[0] == 3/2, y[0] == -1, x'[0] == 3/4}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}];
fx = x /. sols[[1, 1]];
Chop[FindRoot[fx[t] == 1.8, {t, .5}]]
```

which returns {t -> 0.6}

[image]

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your answer. Can you explain to me the use of [[-,- ]] when defining a fx? Thanks

Comment: @Vale look up https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html